# Yii Query Builder Result (Plain Sql With Join And Subquery)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have this syntax on My Controller

```
$checkbook = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT count(b.bookingid) as booking FROM (SELECT :fname AS firstname, :mname AS middlename, :lname AS lastname, :dob AS dob) n 
                                                    LEFT JOIN passenger p ON (p.firstname=n.firstname AND p.middlename=n.middlename AND p.lastname=n.lastname AND p.dob=n.dob)
                                                    LEFT JOIN pax USING (passengerid)
                                                    LEFT JOIN booking b USING (bookingid)
                                                    LEFT JOIN journey USING (bookingid)
                                                    LEFT JOIN flight f USING (flightid)
                                                    WHERE f.origin = :origin AND f.destination = :destination AND f.departure BETWEEN :datestart AND :dateend");
        $checkbook->bindValue(":fname", $fname);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":mname", $mname);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":lname", $lname);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":dob", $dob);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":origin", $origin);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":destination", $destination);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":datestart", $datestart);
        $checkbook->bindValue(":dateend", $dateend);
        $checkbook->queryRow();

        //If Count Result 1, then Status True. If Count Result more than 1,then false. 
        if ($checkbook['booking'] == 1) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $this->actionDoubleBook();
            $status = false;
            return $status;
        }
```

But I got this Error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CDbCommand as array in /home/apihost/public_html/goflight/protected/controllers/BookingController.php on line 653
```

Any idea? And How to make A Good Query Builder with SQL Syntax like that.

Comment: `$checkbook` variable contains CDbCommand object. And you try to access query results using this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the result.. `queryRow()` will not change the query object itself but returns the result. Therefore use this

```
$result = $checkbook->queryRow();
```

then

```
 if ($result['booking'] == 1) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $this->actionDoubleBook();
            $status = false;
            return $status;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, It WOrks. How Silly Iam im just made a little mistake

Comment: happens to everyone once in a while :)